# String class in stl c++ project

Tags: c++, string, stl

Is it possible to create String class with String.cpp and String.h in c++ stl project?

```
String.h

#include <string> 
class String {
public:
    static std::string Replace(const std::string& str, const std::string& oldValue, const std::string& newValue);
};
```

There are compilation errors unless the class is renamed to something else like Stringy

Comment: What compilation errors specifically?

Comment: `static class …` doesn’t do what you think it does (but it’s unrelated to your problem). Apart from that, having such a class with static methods is bad style in C++.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I also found this useful for this particular case: Adding methods grouped in a class (containing only static methods) for enhanced string manipulation. Me and my colleagues didn't want to introduce an extra namespace for this (such kind of classes we've placed in Common::Utilities). Additionally we've declared default constructor and the destructor of such classes as private, to make it more clear they're 'static'.

Comment: @g-makulik But a class like this *does* introduce a new namespace – albeit with some different semantics. The real solution is to use a plain namespace here, not a class. Why would you be reluctant to use a namespace here anyway?

Comment: @KonradRudolph May be, because I was programming in C# for a while and liked th concept of static classes. This style will also resolve some problems if client's can just use a `using namespace Common::Utilities;` in their implementation files you can get when referring to partial subsequent namespaces.

Comment: @g-makulik Well that’s the client’s problem for using namespaces incorrectly. Namespaces are *definitely* the way to go in C++. “static classes” such as here are an anti-pattern (they have a place, but only for so-called traits classes, i.e. where implementations will differ depending on template specialisations). In fact, static classes in C# and Java are a work-around for the fact that every method *has* to be part of a class. C++ doesn’t have the problem in the first place, and thus doesn’t need the workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of a class with only static members, you use a namespace in C++.

```
#include <string>

namespace String {
    std::string Replace(const std::string& str, const std::string& oldValue, const std::string& newValue);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the static from the class declaration and your posted code works just fine then.

Comment: Didn't spot that at 1st look. This is probably the right answer.

Comment: sorry that was my mistype, there is no static in original file